# Change the scroll width of the Delphi IDE Editor window

Tags: delphi, editor

I can find two separate setting in the Delphi (XE) IDE that affect the editor width:

1) the right margin setting under [Editor Options][Display]

2) the right margin setting under [Formatter][Delphi][Line Breaks]

The 1st option only seems to affect the width of the visible right margin in the editor, the 2nd option affects the wrap width of the auto-formatter. Neither seems to affect the actual width of the editor w.r.t. the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the window. Scrolling to the far edge of the window gives a width of 4097 characters.

Is there any way to reduce the overall width of the editor window? Is there any way to auto-wrap as I type?

Comment: they are insinuating what you should use line breaks instead, really

Comment: Yep, I can see that, but does anyone really use line lengths of 4096 characters in their code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "width" of the code editor and the scroll range for the horizontal scroll bar are based on the maximum visible columns which is 4096 characters.  There is no setting in the options to override this value, nor is there a way to have the editor auto-wrap.

The visible right margin setting also controls how where code is wrapped when using class completion (shift-ctrl-c) or adding events.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the purpose of the Right margin - I find it a bit odd that the formatter does not use it.

Comment: It probably should.  However, the code formatter is completely separate from the code editor kernel and GUI so that's why it's not a shared setting.